# Convert BASE64 String to PDF file in the IFS on AS400

Tags: base64, pdf-generation, ibm-midrange, rpg

We receive a  BASE64 encoded representation of a courier label PDF in an xml file, which we store in the IFS of our AS400.

We would like to decode this BASE64 string and save it as a .PDF in the IFS so we can then either email it as an attachment or send it to a printer.

I have looked at the capability of the CPYSPLF command using the *PDF WSCST parameter, but this only seems relevant where we would have a Spooled File representation of the label we want to produce.

Does anyone know if this is possible via native iSeries commands/RPG?

Comment: One way is to use [`IFS_READ_UTF8`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=is-ifs-read-ifs-read-binary-ifs-read-utf8-table-functions) to load th XML file, [`XMLPARSE`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-xmlparse) to make it a XML object [`XML_TABLE`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-xmltable) to extract BASE64 data, [`BASE64_DECODE`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-base64-decode) to get PDF stream and finally [`IFS_WRITE_BINARY`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=is-ifs-write-ifs-write-binary-ifs-write-utf8-procedures) to write as .pdf

Answer (score 1):

One way is to

1. [`IFS_READ_UTF8`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=is-ifs-read-ifs-read-binary-ifs-read-utf8-table-functions) to load the XML file
2. [`XMLPARSE`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-xmlparse) to make it a XML object
3. [`XML_TABLE`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-xmltable) to extract BASE64 data
4. [`BASE64_DECODE`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-base64-decode) to decode B64 data to PDF binary stream
5. [`IFS_WRITE_BINARY`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=is-ifs-write-ifs-write-binary-ifs-write-utf8-procedures) to write that stream as a .pdf file

You could make it a pure sql prodecure, or a SQLRPGLE program.

You also could extract BASE64 date using RPGLE [`XML-INTO`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=codes-xml-into-parse-xml-document-into-variable). The use Scott Klement's [BASE64](https://www.scottklement.com/base64/) SRVPGM to decode it, then write it to the [IFS](https://www.scottklement.com/rpg/ifs.html)